# accessing GPS data using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-gps

HI,
How do I get data from gps module from my windows mobile phone?

Is it through serial port communication?

And how do I transform this data?

Is there any article out there?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [GPS Sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158699.aspx) that shows how to wrap native GPS calls with C#.